# Two-way arrows above and below equation

Tags: amsmath, arrows

I created some Latex Matrix equations. I want to create a matrix dimensions workflow:

```
\begin{align}
    &\hphantom{(2\times 3)( }%
        \overbrace{\hphantom{1 \times 3) = 2 \times 1} } \nonumber \\[-07pt]%
    &( \underbrace{ 2\times 
        \underbrace{
            3) ( 1 \times 3
            }%
        ) = ( 2 } %
    \times 1) \nonumber
\end{align}
```

The result is [image] I have used `\overbrace` to create the braces over my workflow.
I want the same result, but without `\overbrace`, and with (two sided) arrows instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use `\overleftrightarrow` and `\underleftrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}    
\begin{align}
    &\hphantom{(2\times 3)( }%
        \overleftrightarrow{\hphantom{1 \times 3) = (2 \times 1} } \nonumber \\[-07pt]% 
    &( \underleftrightarrow{ 2\times
        \underleftrightarrow{
            3) ( 1 \times 3
            }% 
        ) = ( 2 } %
    \times 1) \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows]

Comment: Oke i think i wasn't clear about the type of arrows i want…
this kind of arrows
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5239536/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-11%20at%2010.31.04.png

The image is from a lecture a few years ago so i don't know how to make that kind of arrows and can't ask it anny more...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tikzmark`. The options `overlay` and  `remember picture` must be added to the subsequent `tikzpicture`. You will need to compile the document several times when you make changes.

[image]

Note that you can move the nodes and the arrows will follow if you make changes, such as placing the matrix dimensions in the standard way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\[
(\tikzmarknode{A}{2}\times\tikzmarknode{B}{3})(\tikzmarknode{C}{1}\times\tikzmarknode{D}{3})
    =(\tikzmarknode{E}{2}\times\tikzmarknode{F}{1})
\]

%\[
%(\tikzmarknode{A}{2}\times\tikzmarknode{B}{3})(\tikzmarknode{D}{3}\times\tikzmarknode{C}{1})
%   =(\tikzmarknode{E}{2}\times\tikzmarknode{F}{1})
%\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
    \draw [<->] (A.south) --++(0,-.3) -| (E.south);
    \draw [<->] (B.south) --++(0,-.2) -| (D.south);
    \draw [<->] (C.north) --++(0,.2) -| (F.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```